# How can I modify and extend properties of an object located in useState Array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a react.js beginner, searching for methods to alter my data structure. For example, I want to push new objects into the children-array or remove them by key.

What is the appropriate way to do that?

```
const [treeData, setTreeData] = useState([
  {
    title: "parent 1",
    key: "0-0",
    icon: <UserAddOutlined />,
    children: [
      {
        title: "parent 1-0",
        key: "0-0-0",
        icon: <UserAddOutlined />,
        children: [
          {
            title: "leaf",
            key: "0-0-0-0",
            icon: <UserAddOutlined />,
          },
          {
            title: "leaf",
            key: "0-0-0-1",
            icon: <UserAddOutlined />,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        title: "parent 1-1",
        key: "0-0-1",
        icon: <UserAddOutlined />,
        children: [
          {
            title: "sss",
            key: "0-0-1-0",
            icon: <UserAddOutlined />,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```

Comment: There are quite a few `children` arrays: to which one are you referring? Also, if you already tried something, please add that code to your question so we can see where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

So you should not update the state directly. It is not allowed.

[image]

Maybe where you are receiving data from, suppose via api and the data is `response.payload.data` etc.

So in your case use the `setTreeData(response.payload.data)` method to add stuff in it.

Now if you want to update certain value (remove or update using index etc). Obviously you will have to have index somehow.

So for deleting say you will have some click and against that a handler for it

```
removeItem(e) {
  item_to_remove = e.target..... etc // to get the item's reference for matching
setTreeData(treeData.filter(items => item.<someproperty> != item_to_remove))
// In your case could also be targetting children maybe
// setTreeData(treeData.Children.filter(items => item.<someproperty> != item_to_remove))
}
```

I would say maybe handle childrens' array inside another useState variable (`childrenTreeData` maybe). But you will have to look it's feasibility too. Just an idea after seeing your data

**JUST for INFO**

This is something similar I did for updating prices inside each cards in my project

```
  const getCurrentPrice = useCallback(() => {    // <======= maybe you do not need this
    const updatedTilesData = tilesData.map((tile: any) => {
      return {
        ...tile,  // <======= get everything here and then update the price below for item
        currentPrice: calculateDNCurrentPrice(
          tile.startingPrice,
          tile.dnTimestamp
        ),
      };
    });
    setTilesData(updatedTilesData);
  }, [tilesData]);
```